# Cast / convert a column but getting error

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in database table defined as `varchar(1000) null`

In one of the situations, the data is entered as `N/A` - so I can force to ignore all values and use null.

But there are some values which I want to use.

If I use `cast`, `convert`, `try_cast`, `tryconvert`, to `varchar` all fails, but if I do it to `int`, it works, but the `try cast`, `try convert` works.

I am not sure why it is failing when I use `try_cast` and it says:

> convert failed to convert N/A value to int.

Even I am not converting it to `INT`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps if you could post more details - what is you SQL and what errors are you getting.

Comment: We need a [MRE] with a query and a sample dataset with causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @test_val  AS varchar(100) = 'N/A'
SELECT TRY_CAST(@test_val AS int)
```

This gives a result of `NULL`

```
DECLARE @test_val  AS varchar(100) = '3'
SELECT TRY_CAST(@test_val AS int)
```

Gives a result of `3`.

It may be that your SQL has a syntax error.